# What is Xpath injection and wether websites with mysql databases are prone to this injection?

Tags: mysql, xpath

I have a website online and when i scanned the website with webcruiser(web vuln scanner) software it found results for Xpath injection. I want to know whether websites with mysql databases were prone to this kind of attack

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is XPath injection ...

This article contains the answers to your questions:

**http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xpathinjection/index.html**

> I want to know whether websites with mysql databases were prone to
>   this kind of attack

**The risk of XPath injection is irrelevant on the RDBMS used** -- it is only related on whether a web application constructs a raw (not precompiled) XPath expression parts of which are taken from the end-user's input.

**To avoid XPath injection one must precompile the XPath expression in advance** with any parts that correspond to user-entered values -- specified as variables/parameters.